# How can I determine if running tar will cause disk to fill up

Tags: tar, disk-usage

If I run `tar -cvf` on a directory of size 937MB to create an easily downloadable copy of a deeply nested folder structure, do I risk filling the disk given the following `df -h` output:

```
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  3.6G  4.3G  46% /
tmpfs                 298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm
```

Related questions:

- If the disk might fill up, why i.e. what will Linux (Amazon AMI) and/or `tar` be
  doing under the hood?
- How can I accurately determine this information    myself without
  asking again?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible without processing the archive, but you can play around with `--totals` option. Either way if you fill the disk up you can simply delete the archive, imho. To check all options available you could go through `tar --help`.

Comment: Tangentially: don't create the tarfile as root, a certain percentage of space on the disk is set aside for root exclusively, exactly for the kind of "I've filled the disk and now I can't login because that would write .bash_history or whatever" situation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`tar -c data_dir | wc -c`
*without compression*

or

`tar -cz data_dir | wc -c`
*with gzip compression*

or

`tar -cj data_dir | wc -c`
*with bzip2 compression*

will print the size of the archive that would be created in bytes, without writing to disk. You can then compare that to the amount of free space on your target device.

You can check the size of the data directory itself, in case an incorrect assumption was made about its size, with the following command:

`du -h --max-depth=1 data_dir`

As already answered, tar adds a header to each record in the archive and also rounds up the size of each record to a multiple of 512 bytes (by default). The end of an archive is marked by at least two consecutive zero-filled records. So it is always the case that  you will have an uncompressed tar file larger than the files themselves, the number of files and how they align to 512 byte boundaries determines the extra space used.

Of course, filesystems themselves use block sizes that maybe bigger than an individual file's contents so be careful where you untar it, the filesystem may not be able to hold lots of small files even though it has free space greater than the tar size!

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Format_details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29#Format_details)

Comment: Thanks Jamie! What is '- mysql' doing here? Is that your filename?

Comment: Just changed that... it is the path to your data directory.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but using the argument combination `-f -` to tar is redundant, since you can simply leave out the `-f` argument altogether to write the result to stdout (i.e. `tar -c data_dir`).

Answer (score 6):

The size of your tar file will be 937MB plus the size of the metadata needed for each file or directory (512 bytes per object), and padding added to align files to a 512-byte boundary.

A very rough calculation tells us that another copy of your data will leave you with 3.4GB free.  In 3.4GB we have room for about 7 million metadata records, assuming no padding, or fewer if you assume an average of 256 bytes' padding per file.  So if you have millions of files and directories to tar, you might run into problems.

You could mitigate the problem by

- compressing on the fly by using the `z` or `j` options to `tar`
- doing the `tar` as a normal user so that the reserved space on the `/` partition won't be touched if you run out of space.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a lot of research on this. You can do a test on the file with a word count but it will not give you the same number number as a `du -sb adir`.

```
tar -tvOf afile.tar | wc -c
```

`du` counts every directory as 4096 bytes, and `tar` counts directories as 0 bytes.  You have to add 4096 to each directory:

```
$(( $(tar -tvOf afile.tar 2>&1 | grep '^d' | wc -l) * 4096)))
```

then you have have to add all of the characters. For something that looks like this:

```
$(( $(tar -tvOf afile.tar 2>&1 | grep '^d' | wc -l) * 4096 + $(tar -xOf afile.tar | wc -c) ))
```

I am not sure if this is perfect since I didn't try files that have been touched (files of 0 bytes) or files that have 1 character. This should get you closer.

Answer (score 2):

`tar` itself can report on the size of its archives with the `--test` option:

```
tar -cf - ./* | tar --totals -tvf -
```

The above command writes nothing to disk and has the added benefit of listing the individual filesizes of each file contained in the tarball. Adding the various  `z/j/xz` operands to either side of the `|pipe` will handle compression as you will.

#### OUTPUT:

```
...
-rwxr-xr-x mikeserv/mikeserv         8 2014-03-13 20:58 ./somefile.sh
-rwxr-xr-x mikeserv/mikeserv        62 2014-03-13 20:53 ./somefile.txt
-rw-r--r-- mikeserv/mikeserv       574 2014-02-19 16:57 ./squash.sh
-rwxr-xr-x mikeserv/mikeserv        35 2014-01-28 17:25 ./ssh.shortcut
-rw-r--r-- mikeserv/mikeserv        51 2014-01-04 08:43 ./tab1.link
-rw-r--r-- mikeserv/mikeserv         0 2014-03-16 05:40 ./tee
-rw-r--r-- mikeserv/mikeserv         0 2014-04-08 10:00 ./typescript
-rw-r--r-- mikeserv/mikeserv       159 2014-02-26 18:32 ./vlc_out.sh
Total bytes read: 4300943360 (4.1GiB, 475MiB/s)
```

Not entirely sure of your purpose, but if it is to download the tarball, this might be more to the point:

```
ssh you@host 'tar -cf - ./* | cat' | cat >./path/to/saved/local/tarball.tar
```

Or to simply copy with `tar`:

```
ssh you@host 'tar -cf - ./* | cat' | tar -C/path/to/download/tree/destination -vxf -
```

Comment: The reason I am doing this is that I believe the directory in question has caused the output of df -i to reach 99%. I want to keep a copy of the directory for further analysis but want to clear the space

Comment: @codecowboy In that case, you should definitely do something like the above first. It will `tar` then copy the tree to your local disk in a stream without saving anything to the remote disk at all, after which you can delete it from the remote host and restore it later. You should probably add `-z` for compression as goldilocks points out, to save on bandwidth mid-transfer.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' No, because it's 99% of inodes, not 99% of space.

Comment: `-i` right, sorry!

Comment: @mikeserv your opening line mentions the --test option but you then don't seem to use it in your command which immediately follows (it uses --totals)

Comment: @codecowboy `-tvf` = `test verbose file`

Answer (score 1):

`-cvf` does not include any compression, so doing that on a ~1 GB folder will result in a ~1 GB tar file (Flub's answer has more details about the additional size in the tar file, but note even if there are 10,000 files this is only 5 MB). Since you have 4+ GB free, no you will not fill the partition.

> *an easily downloadable copy*

Most people would consider "easier" synonymous with "smaller" in terms of downloading, so you should use some compression here.  `bzip2` should now-a-days be available on any system w/ tar, I think, so including `j` in your switches is probably the best choice.  `z` (`gzip`) is perhaps even more common, and there are other (less ubiquitous) possibilities with more squash.

If you mean, does `tar` use additional disk space temporarily in performing the task, I am pretty sure it does not for a few reasons, one being it dates back to a time when tape drives were a form of primary storage, and two being it has had decades to evolve (and I am certain it is not necessary to use temporary intermediate space, even if compression is involved).

Answer (score 0):

If speed is important and compression is not needed, you can hook the syscall wrappers used by `tar` using `LD_PRELOAD`, to change `tar` to calculate it for us. By reimplementing a few of these functions to suit our needs (calculating the size of potential output tar data), we are able eliminate a lot of `read` and `write` that is performed in normal operation of `tar`. This makes `tar` much faster as it doesn't need to context switch back and forth into the kernel anywhere near as much and only the `stat` of the requested input file/folder(s) needs to be read from disk instead of the actual file data.

The code below includes implementations of the `close`, `read`, and `write` POSIX functions. The macro `OUT_FD` controls which file descriptor we expect `tar` to use as the output file. Currently it is set to stdout.

`read` was changed to just return the success value of `count` bytes instead of filling buf with the data, given that the actual data wasn't read buf would not contain valid data for passing on to compression, and thus if compression was used we would calculate an incorrect size.

`write` was changed to sum the input `count` bytes into the global variable `total` and return the success value of `count` bytes **only** if file descriptor matches `OUT_FD`, otherwise it calls the original wrapper acquired via `dlsym` to perform the syscall of the same name.

`close` still preforms all of its original functionality, but if the file descriptor matches OUT_FD, it knows that `tar` is done attempting to write a tar file, so the `total` number is final and it prints it to stdout.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OUT_FD 1
uint64_t total = 0;
ssize_t (*original_write)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;
int (*original_close)(int) = NULL;
void print_total(void)
{
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", total);
}

int close(int fd)
{
    if(! original_close)
    {
        original_close = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "close");
    }
    if(fd == OUT_FD)
    {
        print_total();
    }
    return original_close(fd);
}

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
    return count;
}

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    if(!original_write)
    {
        original_write = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
    }
    if(fd == OUT_FD)
    {
        total += count;
        return count;
    }
    return original_write(fd, buf, count);
}
```

Benchmark comparing a solution where the read disk access and all the syscalls of normal tar operation is performed against the `LD_PRELOAD` solution.

```
$ time tar -c /media/storage/music/Macintosh\ Plus-\ Floral\ Shoppe\ \(2011\)\ \[Flac\]/ | wc -c
332308480
real    0m0.457s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.772s
```

```
tarsize$ time ./tarsize.sh -c /media/storage/music/Macintosh\ Plus-\ Floral\ Shoppe\ \(2011\)\ \[Flac\]/
332308480
real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

The code above, a basic build script to build the above as a shared library, and a script with the "`LD_PRELOAD` technique" using it is provided in the repo:
https://github.com/G4Vi/tarsize

Some info on using LD_PRELOAD: https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/

Comment: Code is good, if it works, but can you *describe* what it does?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.